# Last Date from BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently I am starting with BigQuery and I am loading data from a temperature sensor to a table every 15 minutes (it never stops growing).

My table contains data from a sensor that measures different variables. Each row is composed of a timestamp, and values of these measurements at that time (temperature, humidity, wind, wind direction, etc.).

[I.e. Main Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUQEQ.jpg)

The table is already up to 2.5GB and I am making operations to retrieve the AVG temperature from last day.

So everyday, there is an SQL Scheduled Query which gets all the data belonging to "yesterday" and calculates the AVG.

[Scheduled Query to calculate AVG temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFAQZ.jpg)

The problem is that to get the data, the process is querying all the table and as the table is always growing, the query each day is taking more and more effort and time.

Hope somebody helps me with this topic or give some kind of hints or ideas.

Thanks in advance!!

I tried making some views on the table but it is also querying all the data.

Also materialized data and partitioned tables but they dont refresh with new data coming from the main table.

Comment: Can you please share the query plan?

Comment: Let's begin with simpler things: share your table structure and query (as text)

Comment: I have just updated my post, so you can have more specific information about it. The Scheduled Query is already taking 750 MB to make it but everyday is growing as the main table is growing too.

Comment: As a text, please. Also, this is not a table structure. Something like `Create table t1 (col1 integer, ..)` is. If you don't know how: [here](https://www.revisitclass.com/gcp/how-to-get-the-ddl-of-an-existing-table-view-in-bigquery/) is some example how to get it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `project_test.dataset_test.sensor_data`
(
  timestamp STRING,
  temperature FLOAT64,
  humedity FLOAT64,
  wind_speed FLOAT64
);

Comment: Maybe partitioning is something for you: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: have you considered an index?

Comment: Your timestamp is stored as a string not as a datetime.  You are not seeing a benefit of partitioning because the variable is the wrong type.  Change the timestamp to the the right type and then implement partitioning.

Comment: Also note, you have two pictures in your answer, bot are two lines of text.  IT IS MUCH EASIER on people tying to help you to not have pictures in your answers when they can be represented as text.

Comment: I have already tried partitioning which works great, even with the timestamp as string, as I do a casting when I create the new partition. But the issue is that the new table created from partitioning does not refresh with new data that comes to the main table. Should I change the send of data to the new partition created?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing type of column `timestamp` to `DATETIME`.
As it is internally a number operations on it would be much faster.

You'll also need to rewrite `WHERE` clause of your select to

```
timestamp BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - 1 and CURRENT_DATE()
```

You will see massive performance boost to your queries.

Comment: You are right this will have a massive performance boost, but it won't avoid checking the WHERE clause through all the data of the table which is the main issue, as the table never stops growing.

Comment: @Alex, you main issue here that this check through all data is taking long time. If you'll convert column to numeric type, you'll have chance you create reasonable index if it will be needed. Or maybe even partition your table when it will became really large (2.5G is not)

Comment: Actually my main issue is the large amount of data to check in the query. It doesnt really matter the amount of time. I did a partition with the date and I am trying to store the new data coming from the sensor into the new partitioned table. Lets see...